# Unit Test for Service

Tags: java, performance, unit-testing

How do I properly test this method, my test is bellow can someone tell me if its ok or not ?

```
  public List<Book> findByCategory(String category){
    List<Book> bookList = bookRepository.findByCategory(category);

    List<Book> activeBookList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Book book: bookList) {
        if(book.isActive()) {
            activeBookList.add(book);
        }
    }

    return activeBookList;
}
```

This is the test

```
  @Test
        public void findByCategoryTest() throws Exception {
            List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

             expect(bookRepository.findByCategory(anyObject())).andReturn(bookList);

             expect(bookRepository.findByCategory(anyObject())).andReturn(bookList);
            Assert.assertNotNull(bookList);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I am writing is redundant and don't know what do with the return List`?

Comment: I meant my test method don't seem to test anything ? do they ? is it enough what I have written as test , my question is am I really testing the output of the method or not

Comment: you can mock the call and verify the result

Comment: how do I mock the call?

Comment: you mean in my before test setup

Comment: @Before
    public void setUp() {
        bookRepository = createMock(BookRepository.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bookService, "bookRepository", bookRepository);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this does not look like a test for a repository, but a test for a service with a repository injected. That would be a BookService with a BookRepository like this.

```
public class BookService {

    public BookRepository bookRepository;

    public List<Book> findByCategory(String category) {
        List<Book> bookList = bookRepository.findByCategory(category);

        List<Book> activeBookList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Book book : bookList) {
            if (book.isActive()) {
                activeBookList.add(book);
            }
        }

        return activeBookList;
    }

    public void setBookRepository(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }
}
```

Or with constructor injection preferably.

```
public class BookService {

    public BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public List<Book> findByCategory(String category) {
        List<Book> bookList = bookRepository.findByCategory(category);

        List<Book> activeBookList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Book book : bookList) {
            if (book.isActive()) {
                activeBookList.add(book);
            }
        }

        return activeBookList;
    }
}
```

By looking at your code I assume you are using EasyMock (because you are using expect and andReturn), which is something you didn't specify in your question. EasyMock does not support constructor injection as easily as Mockito (it does, but only in recent versions), so you probably need the setter.

Now, using Mockito you can easily mock the repository and add your verifications and assertions like this.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class BookServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BookService bookService;

    @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void findByCategoryTest() throws Exception {
        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setActive(true);

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setActive(false);

        when(bookRepository.findByCategory(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(Arrays.asList(book1, book2));

        List<Book> bookList =  bookService.findByCategory("category1");

        verify(bookRepository).findByCategory(anyString());

        assertNotNull(bookList);
        assertEquals(1, bookList.size());
        assertEquals(book1, bookList.get(0));
    }
}
```

With EasyMock, this would be like this.

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.easymock.EasyMockRunner;
import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.easymock.TestSubject;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class BookServiceTest2 {

    private EasyMockSupport support = new EasyMockSupport();

    @TestSubject
    private BookService bookService = new BookService();

    @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    public void findByCategoryTest() throws Exception {
        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setActive(true);

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setActive(false);

        expect(bookRepository.findByCategory(anyString())).andReturn(Arrays.asList(book1, book2));
        replay(bookRepository);

        List<Book> bookList = bookService.findByCategory("category1");

        support.verifyAll();

        assertNotNull(bookList);
        assertEquals(1, bookList.size());
        assertEquals(book1, bookList.get(0));
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are not testing anything in your example because you are not calling the actual code, you are just setting the expectations of your mocks.

Hope that helps.

Comment: please explain category one, I think it means book1  but assertEquals(book1, booklist.get(0));

Comment: and I ran the test for some reason there are two books in the list even though u set one to false

Comment: "catergory1" is just an example, you can use "foo" or "bar" there, or any other string that is relevant for your domain. I have tested this locally and there is one book in the list as expected, not two. Maybe you have a typo somewhere? Make sure your book.isActive() method actually returns the value of the "active" field.

Comment: my understanding is expect and return records the method we want to test ,

Comment: so why do we use expect repositories and after replay we are using bookservice to test?

Comment: can we use expect (bookservice.findCategoty..... instead of         expect(bookRepository.findByCategory(anyString())).andReturn(Arrays.asList(book1, book2));

Comment: You have to set the expectations for your mocks, which are the collaborators (BookRepository in this case) injected in the class under test, the BookService, not the methods in the class under test itself. So, no, you shouldn't mock the method in the BookService. It would be only possible with partial mocking, which is generally a code smell, and it doesn't really makes sense because that is the method your are trying to test, so you can't mock it. In summary, your understanding about expect and return are not correct in this case. Hope that clarifies things.